# What is a good javascript to automatically determine the users location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, location

Does anyone know any good javascripts (perhaps a google maps thing) that gives the users (meaning where the user is connected to the internet) location in a string.

Something like geolocation but without the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at geolocation api, here's a good article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2023-Geocoding-A-User-s-Location-Using-Javascript-s-GeoLocation-API.htm